# advantage of using enum

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, enums

I was going through one spring hibernate example
http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-remember-me-example-with-hibernate/

Hi, here author used enum for its default initialization(thanks to JB Nizet for understanding this). But without this initialization it will work fine.So is there any other benift for using this enum?

Code using Enum

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_PROFILE")
public class UserProfile {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id; 

    @Column(name="TYPE", length=15, unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String type = UserProfileType.USER.getUserProfileType();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    //hash code implementaion
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        //equals implementation
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserProfile [id=" + id + ",  type=" + type  + "]";
    }


}
```

Enum Implementation

```
public enum UserProfileType {
    USER("USER"),
    DBA("DBA"),
    ADMIN("ADMIN");

    String userProfileType;

    private UserProfileType(String userProfileType){
        this.userProfileType = userProfileType;
    }

    public String getUserProfileType(){
        return userProfileType;
    }

}
```

(My original question was how call is reaching to getUserProfileType function and how the enum get initialized.Thanks JB Nizet for your previous comments.)

Answer (score 0):

The database script populating the database contains

```
INSERT INTO APP_USER_USER_PROFILE (user_id, user_profile_id)
SELECT user.id, profile.id FROM app_user user, user_profile profile
where user.sso_id='sam' and profile.type='ADMIN';
```

So Sam has one UserProfile, and the type of this profile is 'ADMIN'.

The field `type` in the UserProfile entity is mapped to the column `type` of the table `user_profile`.

Comment: Thank you JB Nizet for your quick response. I made some change in the question to make my doubt clear. could you please go through it.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean in your addendum. I don't know how you defined the column TESTTYPE in the database, what value you stored in this column, how getTestUserProfileType() is defined, and what you're debugging.

Comment: I changed db data from—->
INSERT INTO USER_PROFILE(type) VALUES ('ADMIN');
To—-> 
INSERT INTO USER_PROFILE(type,testtype) VALUES ('ADMIN','TESTADMIN');

And I simply used getter/setter for testUserProfileType in enum definition
public String getTestUserProfileType() {return testUserProfileType;}

public void setTestUserProfileType(String testUserProfileType) {this.testUserProfileType = testUserProfileType;}
I tried to debug at getTestUserProfileType

Comment: Edit the question and post all the relevant code, along with a test case. And post the code **as code** not as a quote.

Comment: sure I will do like that

Comment: Hi I have added the code in GitHub.please find the changed file:https://github.com/jaisonsteephen/EnumDoubtClarification/blob/master/src/main/java/com/websystique/springsecurity/model/UserProfileType.java

Comment: You never initialize the field `testUserProfileType` in the enum. So it's null. Note that the String value of the field in the enum is just used to initialize the `type` field in the entity with a default value. The field is of type String. The enum is completely irrelevant for JPA. It sees a String field, and populates in with the String value found in the database.

Comment: Thank you JB, for your valuable comments. "I understood your comment :The enum is completely irrelevant for JPA".   But one Question--I thought UserProfileType.DBA, will initialize it. If not, what I should do to initialize it?

Comment: initialize what? Again, I don't understand. Again, you should post the relevant code **in the question**. Not at github.

Comment: you told me that "You never initialize the field testUserProfileType in the enum. So it's null".. that is why I asked you, how i can initialize it...I thought GitHub might convenient to you. sorry later on I will post in question itself

Comment: How is the other field of the enum initialized? (this is not a question. It's a hint).

Comment: You don't seem to understand what a constructor is. Here's the constructor of your enum: `private UserProfileType(String userProfileType){
  this.userProfileType = userProfileType;
 }`. It initializes `this.userProfileType`. But it doesn't initialize `this.testUserProfileType`. So `testUserProfileType` is null. As simple as that.

Comment: Hey JB... Thanks for yoyr hint... I understood... I am getting value in debugger.... thanks ... thanks a lot